# After upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 - Failed to apply network settings. you might not be able to connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine

Tags: bluetooth, connection

I recently upgrade my system from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. In Ubuntu 20.04, I’m unable to connect my Bluetooth headphone with my system (Dell, Inspiron 14, 3000 series). I have also Windows OS where the headphone working properly.

After rebooting the system, I’m getting the following message.

> **Failed to apply network settings**
> you might not be able to connect to the Bluetooth network via this machine

```
g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/DbusService.py”, line 124, in _handle_method_call
ok(method(*args))
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/mechanism/Network.py”, line 57, in _reload_network
nc.apply_settings()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py”, line 384, in apply_settings
self.del_ipt_rules()
File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py”, line 329, in del_ipt_rules
call(["/sbin/iptables", “-t”, table, “-D”, chain] + rule.split(" "))
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py”, line 340, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py”, line 854, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File “/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py”, line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/sbin/iptables’
(0)
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.
With regards
Jhon

Comment: Please try to reinstall BlueMan with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall blueman` and report back.

Comment: Thank you @N0rbert. I already try this but it's not working.

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall iptables` Should fix missing links.